# Instead of creating two m.files in matlab when solving ODEs, how could I use anonymous functions to pass parameters?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, ode

i want these two files to combine into one m.file, instead of using function to define the "monod" with passing parameters, i want to use anonymous functions passing the parameters. So to achieve in combining both two files.

```
%(file 1)
function dcdt = monod(t,c,k,ks,y,b)
dcdt = zeros(2,1);
dcdt(1) = -k*c(2)*c(1)/(ks+c(1));
dcdt(2) = y*k*c(2)*c(1)/(ks+c(1))-b*c(2);
% (file 2) ODE45
k = 3.7;ks=30;y=0.03;b=0.01;
options = odeset('Reltol',1.e-10,'AbsTol',1.e-10);
[t,c] = ode45(@monod, [0,200],[200,1],options,k,ks,y,b);
% plot 
C = c(:,1);
Xa = c(:,2);
figure(1);
grid on;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,C);
title('Substrate aqueous concentration vs time(ODE45)');
xlabel('time');ylabel('Substrate aqueous concentration C')
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,Xa);
title('Active-cell concentration vs time');
xlabel('time');ylabel('Active-cell concentration Xa(ODE45)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define a nested function within your file.  Perfectly acceptable syntax.  However, you will need to make File #2 an actual function as you can't define nested functions with a script file.  To do this, just make it a function that accepts no inputs and returns nothing.  :

```
function run_ode %// Change here

    %// Include monod function here - watch the end keyword
    function dcdt = monod(t,c,k,ks,y,b)
        dcdt = zeros(2,1);
        dcdt(1) = -k*c(2)*c(1)/(ks+c(1));
        dcdt(2) = y*k*c(2)*c(1)/(ks+c(1))-b*c(2);
    end %<----

%// Begin File #2
k = 3.7;ks=30;y=0.03;b=0.01;
options = odeset('Reltol',1.e-10,'AbsTol',1.e-10);
[t,c] = ode45(@monod, [0,200],[200,1],options,k,ks,y,b);
% plot 
C = c(:,1);
Xa = c(:,2);
figure(1);
grid on;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,C);
title('Substrate aqueous concentration vs time(ODE45)');
xlabel('time');ylabel('Substrate aqueous concentration C')
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,Xa);
title('Active-cell concentration vs time');
xlabel('time');ylabel('Active-cell concentration Xa(ODE45)');

end %// Take note of this end too as we now have nested functions
```

Copy and paste the above code into a file called `run_ode.m`, then in the MATLAB Command Prompt, type in `run_ode` and push <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
>> run_ode
```

You should get your desired results.

---

Alternatively, if you want to make use of anonymous functions as referenced in your question title, you can do this instead:

```
%// Change here
monod = @(t,c,k,ks,y,b) [-k*c(2)*c(1)/(ks+c(1)); y*k*c(2)*c(1)/(ks+c(1))-b*c(2)];

k = 3.7;ks=30;y=0.03;b=0.01;
options = odeset('Reltol',1.e-10,'AbsTol',1.e-10);
[t,c] = ode45(monod, [0,200],[200,1],options,k,ks,y,b); %// Change here too
% plot 
C = c(:,1);
Xa = c(:,2);
figure(1);
grid on;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,C);
title('Substrate aqueous concentration vs time(ODE45)');
xlabel('time');ylabel('Substrate aqueous concentration C')
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,Xa);
title('Active-cell concentration vs time');
xlabel('time');ylabel('Active-cell concentration Xa(ODE45)');
```

`monod` is now an anonymous function that takes in the 6 inputs, and outputs a two element column vector for use in `ode45`.  Take note that `ode45` is now changed so that the `@` is removed.  `monod` is now already a handle to an anonymous function and so using `@` is not required.

Comment: Pass those additional parameter [via a closure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html#bsgprpq-8), not by adding them after `options` (the style from 10+ years ago -slower too if I recall): `@(t,c)mond(t,c,k,ks,y,b)`. Sub-functions (a.k.a. local functions) also work fine if the integration function is too complex for an anonymous function and you don't/can't use a nested function.

Comment: @horchler - Come pass by the MATLAB chat room for a visit if you have time :) Trying to gather everyone who frequents the tag there as a way of keeping contact.  Optional... totally up to you! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave